# Translator is not loading correct locale

Tags: php, symfony, translation, symfony4

I'm trying to use symfony [sticky locale](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) to change the web locale through the url. For this as is explained y the page y linked before I've created a event subscriber which implements this on onKernelRequest function.

The Event subricreber is running and doing de if($loc) block correctly, but it seems not to be detected by the translator, so it could be a event subcriber priority problem, but I tried to change its priority an still getting same local.

Event Subscriber

```
<?php
// src/EventSubscriber/LocaleSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }
        $loc = $request->attributes->get('_locale');

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($loc) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $loc);
            $request->setLocale($loc);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller

```
/**
* @Route("/{_locale}/pro/live")
*/
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('pro/live/index.html.twig');
}
```

I'm expecting to get change the translator locale to which is writed in the url.

If I change the url to `/en/pro/live/` `$request->getLocale()` in the controller returns the correct locale but the translator local still in `es`

Comment: hey, I would assume that your configuration doesn't include the `en` locale. check config/packages/framework.yaml (that's probably the place). try https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration and the linked pages ("the locale and the url"). this should actually work automatically and no listener/subscriber should be necessary. Really.

Comment: I don't have default locale in config/packages/framework.yaml. Yes, It seems to work in the same way without the event subscriber. But the problem is that when I change the locale in the url the translator is no changing its locale

Comment: on https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html it says, locale on the request must be set before the locale listener, which has a priority of 16 by default (which is lower than 20). so this should already work. you might want to check, when and by what the locale on the request and/or translator is set by manually dumping the stacktrace in the appropriate objects (`Translator::setLocale` and `Request::setLocale`) and investigate further. Also: I hope you're not running on prod and forgot to refresh the cache ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the previos developer had created an event subscriber that changes the translator locale. Whitout it works perfectly